Adding or Deleting Columns in Named Range & Copy Formulas
I have a worksheet that I am trying to add or remove a column(s) in a named range "DA_Data". The range always starts on row 1, and if inserting a column, to only copy formulas and formatting from the column to the left. I need an input box to ask if I want to "Add or Remove" a column.
If Add, I need to be asked "how many to insert" and "At what column letter to insert"
If Remove, I need to be asked "Which column letters to remove"
This excellent code below (thank you again @taller) works like a charm when adding rows, so I was hoping to use this as a basis for the columns, but I'm a bit lost on trying to modify it as it inserts entire rows etc….
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRows2()
    Dim Rng As Range, xTitleId As String
    Dim WorkRng As Range, xLastRow As Long, xRowIndex As Long
    Dim iRow, iCount, i As Long
    'set column reference
    Const COL_INDEX = 2
    xTitleId = "  "
    iCount = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="     How many rows do you want to add?")
    If (Not IsNumeric(iCount)) Or Val(iCount) < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The input is not a valid number"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    iRow = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="After which row do you want to add new rows? (Enter the row number)")
    If (Not IsNumeric(iRow)) Or Val(iRow) < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The input is not a valid number"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set WorkRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Dim formulaRng As Range
    If WorkRng.Columns.Count > 1 Then _
        Set formulaRng = WorkRng.Resize(1, WorkRng.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(COL_INDEX)
    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
    'Set Column to "B"
        Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Row > iRow Then
        'Find "Start" and add rows
            If Rng.Value = "Start" Then
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(iCount).EntireRow.Insert
                If Not formulaRng Is Nothing Then
                    Intersect(Rng.Resize(iCount + 1).EntireRow, formulaRng).FillDown
                    Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(iCount).ClearContents
                End If
            End If
        End If
     Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Call ExclamationMesageBox
End Sub

Below works to add entire columns, not just within my range, but won't copy formulas, so again I'm a bit lost
Sub InsertColumns_Ask()


Dim iCol As Long
Dim iCount As Long
Dim i As Long


iCount = InputBox(Prompt:="How many column you want to add?")


iCol = InputBox _
(Prompt:= _
"After which column you want to add new column? (Enter the column number)")


For i = 1 To iCount
    Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Insert
Next i

End Sub

Any help is greatly appreciated.

And your certain that Columns() is referring to the correct worksheet? A good habit to have when it comes to Excel & VBA is to fully qualify your range objects. Use a variable to store it or at least ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(...).Columns(...)

Hello, and thanks for the comments @K.Davis....The worksheet names will change with every new program so it cannot be static. ultimately im trying to combine multiple examples of code to do what i need but i still have quite a long road ahead for learning VBA. The InsertRows2 code works from a user input for rows. i was hoping someone could help modify for columns in a named range.


The coding logic is similar.

Note: Please backup the file before testing.
Option Explicit

Sub AddRemoveCols()
    Dim colRng As Range, xTitleId As String
    Dim TabRng As Range, targetRng As Range
    Dim sCol As String, iCount, sMode As String
    Const MODE_ADD = "ADD"
    Const MODE_REMOVE = "REMOVE"
    Const END_FLAG = "END"
    xTitleId = "  "
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet  ' modify as needed
    On Error Resume Next
    Set TabRng = oSht.Range("DA_Data") ' DA_Data is a named range
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TabRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't find the named range DA_Data."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sMode = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="     Do you want to add and remove cols?")
    Select Case UCase(sMode)
    Case MODE_ADD
        iCount = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="     How many rows do you want to add?")
        If (Not IsNumeric(iCount)) Or Val(iCount) < 1 Then
            MsgBox "The input is not a valid number"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        sCol = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="At what column letter to insert? (Enter the col name)")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set colRng = oSht.Columns(sCol)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If colRng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The input is not a valid col name"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set targetRng = Application.Intersect(colRng, TabRng)
        If targetRng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The Col is not in the table [DA_Data]"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        targetRng.Resize(, iCount).Insert
        If UCase(sCol) = "A" Then
            MsgBox "Can't copy format and formulas from left col."
        Else
            With targetRng.Offset(, -iCount)
                .Offset(, -1).Copy .Resize(, iCount)
            End With
        End If
        With TabRng
            .Rows(.Rows.Count).Offset(1).Value = END_FLAG
        End With
    Case MODE_REMOVE
        iCount = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="     How many COLs do you want to remove?")
        If (Not IsNumeric(iCount)) Or Val(iCount) < 1 Then
            MsgBox "The input is not a valid number"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        sCol = Application.InputBox(Title:=xTitleId, Prompt:="Which column letter to remove? (Enter the first col name)")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set colRng = oSht.Columns(sCol)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If colRng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The input is not a valid col name"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Application.Intersect(colRng, TabRng) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The Col is not in the table [DA_Data]"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Application.Intersect(colRng.Resize(, iCount), TabRng).Delete shift:=xlShiftToLeft
    Case Else
        MsgBox "The input is invalid."
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Hello @taller, yet again! Thank you very much for the code / input. I have a couple issues.

Is there a way to assign the code to the active worksheet? i noted you have assigned "Sheet1" however the worksheet names will change for each project.
I noticed the code was extending the columns beyond my named range into my data below. I saw TabRng and thought this was a table ref so i converted my named range into a table called DA_Data, and the code will hang after i click on OK after one of the user inputs (not always the same one) i need to force quit.
Appreciate the help as always!



yes, change to Set oSht = ActiveSheet. 2.TabRng is a named range. 3.the code will hang after i click on OK How many cells in the named range? If it is not huge, the performace shouldn't be like that. Try again after restarting Excel.


ActiveSheet updated.
Start range is I1:L51. on average it may expand about 10 columns and 20 rows. Although i have seen it double even that on rare occasions.
I created a new table, just kept the default Table1 name, updated 3 location in the code and it worked 2 out of 5 attempts, however i did just notice it is still adding full columns, not just within the table range. It seems to hang primarily after i select quantity. it brings up the next InputBox but that is where it hangs.

It's important to determine whether you're working with a Table (ListObject) or a named range, as the code required for each scenario can be different.

I added images to the original post per your request. I did notice that the Table range actually starts on row 2 and not row 1. My original Named range started on row 1. I wasn't sure if this could be causing the issue but wanted to make you aware.

I remindered you in my last comment because I knew the difference. It doesn't make any sence to create Table1 in your case because it covers multiple area. What's your final decision, Table or named range?

Would prefer a named range instead of a table. If it would help, the end of the named range, row 52, could have a unique cell value, like the word "END", although any new column added i would ask that the word "End" be added as part of the code too.
